# RxJS: why does subscribing makes no difference

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable, jasmine-marbles

Consider the following service example

```
export class AuthService {
  private observableCache: { [key: string]: Observable<boolean> } = {};
  private resourceCache: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  isGranted(resource): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.resourceCache[resource]) {
      return of(this.resourceCache[resource]);
    }

    if (this.observableCache[role]) {
      return this.observableCache[role];
    }

    this.observableCache[resource] = this.userService
        .getCurrentUser()
        .pipe(map((user: User) => user.canAccess(resource)))
        .pipe(share());

    return this.observableCache[resource];
  }
}
```

In this service I'm checking if user is allowed to review specific resource.

And here is how I'm trying to test it

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  let userService: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    userService = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['getCurrentUser']);
    service = new AuthGuardService(userService);
  });

  describe('isGranted', () => {
    const user: User = {id: 123};

    beforeEach(() => {
      userService.getCurrentUser.and.returnValue(
        hot('-^u', { u: user })
      );
    });

    it('should prove response being cached', () => {
      service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();
      service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();

      expect(userService.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The aim of the test is to check that resource cache works. But what I notice, is that if I replace the following snippet

```
  service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();
  service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();
```

With simple

```
  service.isGranted('dashboard');
  service.isGranted('dashboard');
```

The test still works, I'm new to RxJS and marble testing, but as far as I know, Observable should not work until subscribed.

The question - why does it works both ways?

Comment: You're not testing that an Observable chain is created or not. You're just testing whether `userService.getCurrentUser` is called and it is called every time you invoke `isGranted`. So this is unrelated to RxJS.

Comment: why does `userService.getCurrentUser` being executed at all without casting subscribe? As I got from RxJS docs, computation is only happens for each Observer that subscribes

Comment: It has nothing to do with RxJS. You call that method when you call `isGranted` just like any other method in any other JavaScript code.

Comment: @martin could you please provide an example of how this test should look like? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code the test is working with is asynchronous, try running it using `fakeAsync` and `tick`

```
it('should prove response being cached', fakeAsync(() => {
  service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();
  service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe();
  tick();
  expect(userService.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

Look at https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service for more information.

Comment: Thank you! This test case pass, as well as mine! Could you please extend your answer and provide an explanation? Right now I'm looking an answer rather than code snippets

Comment: Take a look at the event loop in JavaScript, specially on Macro- and Micro tasks. In Async calls, Javascript may "switch" between tasks, so that you do not know which is executed when. The "service.isGranted('dashboard').subscribe()" starts a microtask. With the "fakeAsync" you put the whole code into a kind of sandbox. And with "tick()" you tell the sandbox to execute all open microtasks. If you dont do that, your unit test may be finished before the microtask was executed.. Warm regards Jan